# meeting three conditions from a file

Tags: python

suppose I have the following file (which is in [PDB format](http://www.wwpdb.org/))

```
     ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      66.104  56.583 -35.505  1.00  0.00           N 
     ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1      66.953  57.259 -36.531  1.00  0.00           C
     ATOM      3  C   MET A   1      67.370  56.262 -37.627  1.00  0.00           C
     ATOM      4  O   MET A   1      67.105  55.079 -37.531  1.00  0.00           O
     ATOM      5  CB  MET A   1      68.227  57.852 -35.867  1.00  0.00           C
     ATOM      6  CG  MET A   1      67.848  58.995 -34.899  1.00  0.00           C
     ATOM      7  SD  MET A   1      66.880  58.593 -33.421  1.00  0.00           S
     ATOM      8  CE  MET A   1      68.253  58.332 -32.269  1.00  0.00           C
     ATOM      9  H1  MET A   1      66.566  56.636 -34.576  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     10  H2  MET A   1      65.969  55.585 -35.765  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     11  H3  MET A   1      65.179  57.056 -35.460  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     12  HA  MET A   1      66.373  58.046 -36.989  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     13  HB2 MET A   1      68.743  57.078 -35.317  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     14  HB3 MET A   1      68.894  58.236 -36.625  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     15  HG2 MET A   1      68.760  59.479 -34.578  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     16  HG3 MET A   1      67.283  59.729 -35.455  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     17  HE1 MET A   1      68.880  57.524 -32.617  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     18  HE2 MET A   1      67.847  58.062 -31.306  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     19  HE3 MET A   1      68.822  59.245 -32.159  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     21  CA  ALA A   2      68.498  55.965 -39.793  1.00  0.00           C
     ATOM     22  C   ALA A   2      70.028  56.064 -39.893  1.00  0.00           C
     ATOM     23  O   ALA A   2      70.561  56.995 -40.466  1.00  0.00           O
     ATOM     30  N   THR A   3      70.681  55.084 -39.321  1.00  0.00           N
     ATOM     24  CA  ALA A   2      67.833  56.491 -41.076  1.00  0.00           C
     ATOM     25  H   ALA A   2      68.194  57.752 -38.637  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     26  HA  ALA A   2      68.226  54.930 -39.645  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     27  HB1 ALA A   2      66.760  56.401 -40.994  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     28  HB2 ALA A   2      68.167  55.915 -41.926  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     29  HB3 ALA A   2      68.085  57.529 -41.233  1.00  0.00           H
     ATOM     30  N   THR A   3      70.681  55.084 -39.321  1.00  0.00           N
     ATOM     31  CA  THR A   3      72.178  55.028 -39.324  1.00  0.00           C
     ATOM     32  C   THR A   3      72.651  53.933 -40.300  1.00  0.00           C
```

I would like to do some process if N, CA and C all are present sequentially in the file (this condition is true for residue 1 and 3 but false for residue 2). Column 6 shows residue numbers. If I write like follows.

```
     if line[0:6]=='ATOM  ':
       if line[12:16]==' N  ' or line[12:16]==' CA ' or line[12:16]==' C  ':
          do some process
```

But this condition is true for residue 2 also where "N, CA, C" are not in sequence. How to modify the above code to do the process only if "N, CA, C" are in a sequence? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should seriously consider [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), or another tool, for this.

Comment: In your code it should be `for line in f`, not `for line in fn` (`fn` is the filename). Also `line[0:6]` will never be `ATOM ` because `ATOM ` is 5 chars (it should be `line[0:5]`). I couldn't do a test on real files because after wasting some time on wwPDB.org I wasn't able to find where to download a `.pdb` file from.

Comment: `A` is one, `T` is another `O` is third, `M` is fourth and space is fifth. Am I missing something? With that file it "works" (prints the file name many times...)

Comment: actually line[0:6] == 'ATOM  ' if we include the two white spaces as shown in the code above. You are right it will be [0:5] with one white space. You can download the pdb file ( code 1B8Z) from this link rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1B8Z. The download link is on the right hand side in the beginning. Your suggestion to replace fn with f also worked. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could keep a three-element queue

```
q = [None] * 3
for line in lines:
    if line[0:5] == "ATOM ":
        q[0] = q[1]; q[1] = q[2]; q[2] = line[12:16]
        if q == [" N  ", " CA ", " C  "]:
            ... found a match ...
```

if other elements are allowed (but you need the sequence of N, CA and C) you can enter the elements in the queue only if they are N, CA or C ignoring other elements.

It's also easy to extend this processing to search for different sequences at the same time.

Comment: @user2176228: `lines` is the name I supposed contained the lines of the file. You could also write `for line in open("myfile.dat"):` to loop directly while reading the file (please don't make a comment saying that `myfile.dat` doesn't exist ;-) )

Comment: This answer seems to be OK, but I think it would be better to do `tokens = line.split(' ')` and then remove empty elements `filter(lambda a: a!='', tokens)` and then check the values.

Comment: @SAM: I don't agree. This seems a fixed record file format and just accessing specific characters is IMO better. Of course I never heard about this file format before so I'm not 100% sure.